# Вывод первых двух одинаковых элементов массива

Tags: php

Подскажите, как организовать вывод первых двух одинаковых элементов массива

```
$arr=array('one'=>rand(1,5),'two'=>rand(1,5),'three'=>rand,'four'=>rand(1,5)); 
foreach($arr as $key){
    if($arr[$key]==2)
       echo $arr[key];
}
```

Comment: используйте цикл `for`. тогда сможете сравнивать значение элемента на позиции `i` и на позиции `i-1`, тобишь предыдущей

Comment: сударь не могли бы вы для данного случая написать кодец, а то мне трудно разобраться в данном примере

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте использовать `array_count_values` который даст количество одинаковых значений.

Вот пример

```
<?php
  $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
  print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Как видите тут массив, берите первую `=> 2` и это будет ваш дубликат

Comment: Класс! Я думал прделожить сортировать по значениям, но этот вариант однозначно круче!

Answer (score 2):

Вывод (первых)-x (двух)-x (одинаковых) (элементов) массива

Ок массив есть.

КОД

```
$arr=array('one'=>rand(1,5),
'two'=>rand(1,5),
'three'=>rand(1,5),
'four'=>rand(1,5)
);

print_r($arr);

foreach($arr as $n=>$v){ //БЕГАЕМ
    unset($arr[$n]);//УБИВАЕМ ССЫЛКУ НА ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ
    foreach($arr as $n2=>$v2){
        if($v2==$v){
            echo '(NAME:'.$n.' VALUE:'.$v.') AND ('.'NAME:'.$n2.' VALUE:'.$v2.')';
            break 2;
        }

    }
}
```

ВЫВОД:

```
Array
(
    [one] => 2
    [two] => 4
    [three] => 2
    [four] => 1
)
(NAME:one VALUE:2) AND (NAME:three VALUE:2)
```

Если я понел все верно.

Comment: Красава , всё просто и понятно.Спасибо!